# 301 Redirect for IP address with standard WordPress .htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

For IP canonicalization, I'm told I need to redirect the IP address of the site to the domain name. I'm running a standard WordPress install that already comes with it's own .htaccess file. I modified it below by adding the "Redirect" line:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

Redirect 301 http://12.34.56.789 http://www.domainname.com

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

However, it's not working. Anyone know what is wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You generally don't want to mix `Redirect` (mod_alias) with `RewriteRule` (mod_rewrite) because they both get applied to the same URI and will clobber each others changes sometimes. Just stick with mod_rewrite because you have wordpress rules that already use it.

Replace the

```
Redirect 301 http://12.34.56.789 http://www.domainname.com
```

with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^12\.34\.56\.789$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domainname.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: The rewrite condition could be expressed more loosely as `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$` — there's no need to restrict this rule to a single IP address.

Comment: I didn't realize there was a difference (redirect vs rewriterule). Thanks!

Comment: @squeamishossifrage problem with that is if the server actually listens to multiple IP addresses, and different hostnames could map to different IP's. If you redirect all IPs to a single hostname, you lose that mapping.

Comment: @JonLin We're talking about a .htaccess file here, not httpd.conf

Answer (score 1):

Jon Lin's answer worked for me but I had to use

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^12\.34\.56\.789$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domainname.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

instead of

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^12\.34\.56\.789$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domainname.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```